# How to Bulk Insert from a select query?

Tags: sql-server

I want to Bulk Insert the result of this query into a table. What should I do?

Here is my query :

```
select * 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.code = t2.stucode
```

Answer (score 5):

`bulk insert` is not the term you are looking for. [**`bulk insert`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) imports a data file. You are not importing a data file.

You are looking to create a table based on the results of a query. Which is easily done with [`select ... into`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx).

```
select * 
  into t3
  from table1 t1 
    inner join table2 t2 on t1.code=t2.stucode
```

Alternatively, you can create the table first, and use the minimally logged `bulk load` operation of `insert ... select` with `trace flag 610` for clustered indexes, or no trace flag required for heaps. Find more about the other limitations to this here:
[The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I want to insert large amount of data and bulk insert is very fast that's why I want to use bulk insert.

Comment: @sh.h [**`bulk insert`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) imports a data file. You are not importing a data file.